# Field visible in report but not in object manager

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am working on a report type "Activities with Contacts" and I see that a field called "Last Activity"(date)(api_name: CONTACT_LAST_ACTIVITY) is visible and I am able to add it to the report columns.

I also see that this column is coming from contacts object.

But when I go to object manager and check this in contact's object fields and relationships, this column is not there.

Please let me know if I am missing something. Why is this field visible in report but not anywhere else?

I have checked this column in task, activities, events, accounts objects as well.

Also, this field is not visible in field sets.

Answer (score 0):

Last Activity is a calculated field, it depends in a lot of conditions. It's not in the list of fields of the object. More info about the calculation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385365&type=1

If you need it as a field in the object, you can create a formula field that uses the field `LastActivityDate`, like the example in salesforce help for the lead object: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387759&type=1